# add_action in wp_head accessible from class

Tags: php, actions

Given this code:

```
class test_class {

    function greeting() {
        echo 'Howdy! Test is successful!';
    }

    function greeting_head() {
      //Close PHP tags
    ?>
        <?php greeting() ?>
    <?php //Open PHP tags
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', array( 'test_class', 'greeting_head' ) );
```

`greeting()` is undefined. How to access if from outside `test_class`?

UPDATE: I wound up using Sally J.'s solution

PREVIOUS UPDATE: I tried Adnane's solution and it didn't work, but it put me on the trail of the correct answer.

```
class test_class {

    public static function greeting() {
        return 'Howdy! Test is successful!';
    }

    function greeting_head() {
        echo self::greeting();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', array( 'test_class', 'greeting_head' ) );
```

Apparrently I was calling a static function in a non-static way. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860601/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context-in-e-xampp-htdocs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the *static* class method call when supplying a [callable/callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) to `add_action()`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', array( 'test_class', 'greeting_head' ) );
```

So you should make the `greeting_head()` a static method in your `test_class` class. But you'd also need to make the `greeting()` a static method:

```php
class test_class {

    public static function greeting() {
        echo 'Howdy! Test is successful!';
    }

    public static function greeting_head() {
        self::greeting();
    }
}
```

And unless you use a singleton pattern, you'd need to use the `self` keyword to access methods and properties from a static method; for example, in the above code, you could see that I'm using `self::greeting()` and not `$this->greeting()`.

But I wouldn't suggest using static class methods unless *absolutely* necessary, and you can just leave your class as it is now — *except, use `$this->greeting()` in the `greeting_head()` method* — and use the object method call when supplying the `add_action()` callback:

```php
class test_class {

    function greeting() {
        echo 'Howdy! Test is successful!';
    }

    function greeting_head() {
        $this->greeting();
    }
}

$test_class = new test_class;

add_action( 'wp_head', array( $test_class, 'greeting_head' ) );
```

This answer *doesn't* cover everything about classes in PHP, but I hope it helps you; and if you need further guide, you can search on Stack Overflow or even here on WordPress Stack Exchange.. =)

### UPDATE

For completeness,

1. You're getting this error because you're trying to access a *global* function named `greeting` which obviously doesn't exist since PHP threw that error:

   > `greeting()` is undefined.
2. "*How to access if from outside `test_class`?*" — Use the `$this` keyword: `$this->greeting()`, just as @Adnane and I mentioned in our original answer. Or use `self::greeting()` as I stated in my original answer.

   **(Update)** "*if from outside `test_class`*" — Actually, the proper question should be, "how to access the `greeting()` method from another method *in the same class*" because you are actually calling `test_class::greeting()` from `test_class::greeting_head()`. :)
3. And your code as in the current question would result in the following PHP *notice*: (see the `add_action()` note above)

   > Non-static method test_class::greeting_head() should not be called
   >   statically

   In addition, you'd get the following PHP fatal error if you simply use `$this` in your original `greeting_head()`:

   > Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

And for this question:

> Can you point me to some documentation on the pros and cons of using
>   static class methods?

- https://wpshout.com/courses/object-oriented-php-for-wordpress-developers/php-static-methods-in-depth/
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: "But I wouldn't suggest using static class methods unless absolutely necessary […]" Thanks. This works. Can you point me to some documentation on the pros and cons of using static class methods?

Comment: I've just updated the answer; I hope it's more helpful now. But really, searching for "static vs non-static php methods" on Google would give you many good results.. :)

Answer (score -1):

1 - Inside your **class** you are trying to call the function **greeting()** thats not a Method of current **class** so php will try to find this function outside the **class** and will show Fatal error message if function not exists.

to Call this function inside your class you need to call it as method :

```
$this->greeting();
```

2 - Is not a good Idea to use php tags inside **class**

**This is the right Way :**

```
class test_class {

    function greeting() {
        return 'Howdy! Test is successful!';
    }

    function greeting_head() {
        echo $this->greeting();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', array( 'test_class', 'greeting_head' ) );
```

Comment: That didn't work. "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context" See next answer for what did.